# find current, voltage and power at each branch using fourier series analysis

Tags: homework, fourier

Question: find current, voltage and power at each branch using fourier series analysis

[image: photo of schematic]

Update - here is my solution attempt:

[image: solution attempt]

Comment: Okay. By the time I complete your homework, go thru this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: okay.... thank you

Comment: Can you write what steps you followed for each: current, voltage and power. And write it bigger on paper. And click it under proper light. And crop it properly. And edit pics if needed. Right now it looks unrecognisable. Put some sincere effort if you want sincere responses.

Comment: @MituRaj i still cannot find the value of voltage, current and power because my impedance value look weird. then, other example like this question  that i google and watch on youtube solution also look like weird and im not understand

Answer (score 1):

First, I will present a general method of finding your transfer function. I will use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to do it.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLf9fV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, it is not hard to solve for \$\text{V}_1\$:

$$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag3$$

Where I used Mathematica-code to solve for that:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, 
   I3 == V1/R3, I2 == V2/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R2 + R3 + R4) Vi)/(R3 (R2 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> (R3 Vi)/(R3 (R2 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> ((R2 + R4) Vi)/(R3 (R2 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V1 -> (R3 (R2 + R4) Vi)/(R3 (R2 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> (R3 R4 Vi)/(R3 (R2 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))}}
```

---

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\tag4$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\text{sL}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\tag6$$

Using the convolution theorem of the Laplace transform we can find that:

$$\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_4\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\left(\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_4\right)+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_4\right)}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\tag7$$

Using Mathematica, we can see that:

$$\text{V}_1\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\left\{\sum_{\text{n}\ge1}\frac{4\cos\left(\text{n}\tau\right)}{\pi\text{n}^3}\right\}\cdot\mathcal{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_4\right)}{\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\left(\text{sL}+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}+\text{R}_4\right)+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\left(\text{sL}+\text{R}_4\right)}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\tag8$$

Comment: are the method same with fourier series analysis method?